# Why does a sample of $n$ of a population of $n$ retain degrees of freedom of $n$?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, population, degrees-of-freedom

I understand that if you take a sample from the population that a single data point cannot freely vary if $\bar{x}$ is known and you have the remaining sample items. However, I do not understand why "a sample of size $n$ retains $n$ degrees of freedom if the population mean $μ$ is known". The answer is sort of provided in this paper: [Degrees of Freedom](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-9639.2008.00324.x) (Eisenhauer, J.G.), where it states:

> 'Note that a sample of size $n$ retains $n$ degrees of freedom if the population mean μ is known, since this does not determine $x_i$ for $i = 1 ... n$ if the other $(n–1)$ values are known. The concept is of importance in statistical inference since it defines the effective size of a sample.'

Which is actually a quote from "A Dictionary of Mathematics".

Why though, does **knowing $μ$** "not determine $x_i$ for $i = 1 \dots  n$ if the other $(n–1)$ values are known"?

Using the same logic, I can calculate the remaining value if I know $n-1$ values and $μ$. So why are the degrees of freedom still $n$?

My intuitive guess is that by knowing $μ$ I **must** know the entire population of data points. However by the same logic, if I know $\bar{x}$ I must know my entire sample set of data. So I do not understand why the -1 rule does not apply to the population.

The rule seems arbitrary to me, since if the data set is 1000, and I have 999 points, my degrees of freedom are 998, but if my sample is the entire population (1000), then my degrees of freedom are 1000.

My discussion is a bit long winded, so please let me restate my question:

Why does **knowing $μ$** "not determine $x_i$ for $i = 1 ... n$ if the other $(n–1)$ values are known"?

Comment: Great example of a well-asked question (+1). – *Reviewer*

Comment: You can know $\mu$ without knowing the population (consider measurements of electric charge at point locations within a body of net zero charge, for instance); and when a sample is obtained with replacement, then no subset of any sample, no matter how large, will determine the remainder of the sample.  These assertions all follow directly from the mathematical definitions of the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... because the mean of the $n$ values is not $\mu$.

A sample mean would normally be denoted as $\bar{x}$; it's not the case that $\bar{x}=μ$ in general. Consider the case where I have 99 tickets labelled 1,2,...,99. The population average of those values, $μ$, is 50. I draw five of them and get 76, 48, 34, 8, 71, which averages 47.4. If we take the knowledge that the population mean is 50 and the first four sample values were 76, 48, 34, 8 that doesn't really constrain that last value (if we're sampling without replacement there's a few values it can't be, but otherwise it could be any of the other values and so could produce a wide variety of sample means).

Comment: Sorry Glen, that didn't quite clear things up for me. What then is the mean of the n values? Is mu not the population mean?

Comment: A sample mean would normally be denoted as $\bar{x}$; it's not the case that $\bar{x}=\mu$ in general. Consider the case where I have 99 tickets labelled 1,2,...,99. The population average of those values, $\mu$, is 50. I draw five of them and get  76, 48, 34,  8, 71, which averages 47.4. If we take the knowledge that the population mean is 50 and the first four sample values were 76, 48, 34,  8 that doesn't really constrain that last value (if we're sampling without replacement there's a few values it can't be, but otherwise it could be any of the other values).

Comment: The recent activity on this answer made me realize that I did not select an accepted answer. I'll do that now.

Comment: Thanks. It occurs to me that if I simply copy the comment up into the answer, it may be sufficient to get rid of the notice (presumably after review). I am not sure it helps the answer, but maybe.

Comment: I think it helps. I understand now much more easily, but being a student new to statistics the concept of "degrees of freedom" is often difficult to grasp when you first encounter it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with a formal answer but I have been thinking about this topic.

I guess that it is about the concept of a restrain.

When you observe the values of a population, if you calculate the population mean you are not actually setting anny restrain, just describing the population with a parameter that happens to be the population mean.

You do eliminate a degree of freedom with the estimation of the sample mean because you force that your population of $n$ to have a sample of $n_s$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n_s} (x_i-\bar x)=0.$$

This is the way I see that; if someone can bring a more complete answer I'd like to read it.